# Move from visual studio online to github

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I've created a project with visual studio online source control, however I've never actually synced with the server, i'm just committing locally.

Now I need to add this project to a github repository, so in the windows github client I've located the project and added it, I can see all of my previous commits, however when I try to sync i'm presented with a dialogue box asking for my VS online credentials.

Does anyone know how I can remove the VS Online account and move the Project to Github?

Cheers!

Comment: Git-TFS Tool: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio uses git for version control, which is consistent with the github client seeing your version history and greatly simplifies things: all you need to do is change the remote reference to point to your github repository.

Github actually has pretty good instructions for changing your remote [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).  To summarize the important bits, from the command prompt run:

```
cd <root directory of your local repository>
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
git fetch
```

Replace `USERNAME` and `REPOSITORY` with appropriate values, and running the fetch should prompt you for your github credentials to confirm it worked.

Comment: VSO uses TFS as source control, but supports Git too... let's hope this is the case. Otherwise, migration will be necessary

Comment: Is the local repository for my VS project in (for example) `C:/../Visual Studio 2015/Projects/MyProject`?